# Removing %20 value from get method

Tags: javascript, android, get

Removing %20 in get method?

```
var c=new Array(a);    
(eg: a={"1","2"})  window.location="my_details.html?"+  c + "_";
```

and in my_details.html :

```
var q=window.location.search;    
alert("qqqqqqqqqqqqq " + q);   
var arrayList = (q)? q.substring(1).split("_"):[];      
var list=new Array(arrayList);    
alert("dataaaaaaaaaaaa " +  list  + "llll " );
```

and in "list" its dusplaying me `"1%202"`;

How can I remove this `%20 =space` value ??

Thanks

Comment: What would you like the `list` parameter to be? `1,2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use this:

```
alert("dataaaaaaaaaaaa " +  decodeURIComponent(list)  + "llll " );
```

This should decode the `%20` to `space`

look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: Please don't link to W3Schools. They are too often wrong. (Half way down that page they forget about the "Component" part and start tossing about whole URLs instead which doesn't make for a good example and yet manages to be one of the best pages W3Schools has).

Comment: do you have a better source than them? I actually don't find a page which has a better example.

Comment: MDN is usually better, although in this case it is actually something of a toss up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: ok, this is somehow just a stub. But I will take MDN in account on others post. I think for this special case w3schools fits best.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space in the parameter(s), then the `%20` (URL Encoding) is necessary. You cannot pass a space in a `GET` request.

If you need to avoid this, use `POST`.

Comment: there is no space. I don't know how %20 is getting added there. I can not use POST. How can i resolve this using GET?

Comment: @Sneha, I'm not sure why that is, but you can use `unescape(text)` function to decode the `%20` into an actual space. Hope that helps.

Comment: `unescape` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem is being introduced at this line:

```
window.location="my_details.html?"+  c + "_";
```

This could be written as:

```
window.location="my_details.html?"+  c.toString() + "_";
```

The *default* `.toString()` of a JavaScript `Array` would be to use a delimiter of `,`, i.e.

```
var str = ["1", "2", "3"].toString(); // 1,2,3
```

In you example it appears that the delimiter being used is a space. This would have been changed by something changing the default behaviour of `.toString()` on the `Array.prototype`. Try using the following:

```
window.location="my_details.html?"+  c.join(",") + "_";
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use replace() method to replace `%20` to `space`

`list.replace("%20"," ");`